# Bibliography in knitr child documents

Tags: r, knitr, bibtex, bibliography

I am having trouble including a bibliography in a `knitr` child document.  I want to be able to reference articles from my main bibliography in a child document, but have the bibliography appear after the main document, not after the child.  If I only include the `\bibliography` command in the main document, the references in the child document are not parsed correctly.  Example:

main.Rnw:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
This is the main doc.

<<child-demo, child='child.Rnw'>>=
@
\bibliography{mylib}
\end{document}
```

child.Rnw:

```
This is the child \cite{myref}.
```

mylib.bib:

```
@article{myref,
 title = {frobnosticating froo filters}
 volume = {21},
 journal = {Frobnification},
 author = {John Q. Smith}
 month = jan,
 year = {2004}
}
```

My `compile` script contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
library(knitr)
knit('main.Rnw', tangle=TRUE)
knit('main.Rnw', tangle=FALSE)
for ( i in c(1,2,3)) {
  system('pdflatex main')
  system('bibtex main')
}
```

Running `compile` produces:

[image: out]

How can I make the child document include references from the main bibliography?

Comment: This is not a Latex question; this is a knitr question.  There are thousands of questions tagged "knitr" on stackoverflow.

Comment: How did you compile the main document? To resolve the references, normally you have to go through the boring process of pdflatex & bibtex & pdflatex & pdflatex, unless you use tools that are smart enough to resolve the references.

Comment: @Yihui--Added my compile script to the question.

Comment: Turns out it _is_ a LaTeX question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you missed a few commas in your `mylib.bib`:

```
@article{myref,
 title = {frobnosticating froo filters},
 volume = {21},
 journal = {Frobnification},
 author = {John Q. Smith},
 month = {jan},
 year = {2004}
}
```

Then you did not specify a bibliography style:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
This is the main doc.

<<child-demo, child='child.Rnw'>>=
@
\bibliography{mylib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```